# Como usar el evento textChanged para sumar y restar en C#

Tags: c#

estoy sumando los datos ingresados por TextBox y llenando en otro TexBox el resultado de forma automática utilizando el evento TextChanged de cada TextBox, cunado ingreso los datos en el TextBox el resultado aparece de forma automática pero si quiero borrar un dato en el TextBox me sale un error, Saben como hacer que sume y que me permita borrar los datos del TextBox y que se restes cada ves que se borre.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta. Es importante que en lugar de una captura copies y pegues tu codigo para que sea mas legible y si alguien quiere probarlo no tenga que teclearlo.

Comment: En cuanto a tu pregunta, el problema es que `TextChanged` se dispara con cada cambio en el textbox, con lo que por ejemplo puede ir un espacio en blanco, o si tecleas un decimal, podria llegarle por ejemplo algo como `1,`. Tienes que validar esas posibilidades antes de intentar parsear a int

Comment: Todo los datos que voy a ingresar son INT, pero si quiero borrar, ingreso una letra o carácter especial también sale error, ¿Cómo hago esas validaciones?

Comment: Tienes varias opciones. Una es simplemente `if (txttransporte.Text!="")`... Otra mas "profesional" seria usar [`TryParse`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-5.0) en lugar de `Parse`

Comment: Podrías mostrarme un ejemplo, ¿si pongo if (txttransporte.Text!="") eso me dejara borrar los datos y se restara automáticamente?

Answer (score 0):

a como dicen los compañeros, antes de parsear deberías validar si existe valor o incluso si el valor digitado es numérico, podrías realizar lo siguiente.

```
    int val = 0;//declaramos variable que almacenará el valor convertido posteriormente
    int.TryParse(txttransporte.Text, out val );//en caso de que el TextBox esté vacío o el valor digitado no sea numérico, asignará valor cero
    text4=val.ToString();
    suma(text1,text2,text3,text4);
```

Espero te sea de ayuda amigo.